# Failed to resolve import "@urql/exchange-graphcache" from "src/routes/$layout.svelte". Does the file exist?

Tags: javascript, yarnpkg, svelte, urql, sveltekit

I have a sveltekit project I have been working on, and configured graphcaching a while ago with @urql/exchange-graphcache. However i just installed a new dependency (dayjs, though i think it is irrelavant), and now it is throwing the error:

```sh
Failed to resolve import "@urql/exchange-graphcache" from "src/routes/$layout.svelte". Does the file exist?
```

I get the same error when I roll back before installing dayjs, and just doing a new yarn install. I tried looking through the [graphcache error page](https://formidable.com/open-source/urql/docs/graphcache/errors/) but found nothing of help. Can anyone help with what might be the error?

If it helps, these are my dependencies

```json
    "dependencies": {
        "@urql/svelte": "^1.2.0",
        "dayjs": "^1.10.4"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@graphql-codegen/cli": "^1.21.3",
        "@graphql-codegen/typed-document-node": "^1.18.4",
        "@graphql-codegen/typescript": "^1.21.1",
        "@graphql-codegen/typescript-operations": "^1.17.15",
        "@graphql-typed-document-node/core": "^3.1.0",
        "@sveltejs/adapter-node": "next",
        "@sveltejs/kit": "next",
        "graphql": "^15.5.0",
        "svelte": "^3.29.0",
        "svelte-preprocess": "^4.0.0",
        "tslib": "^2.0.0",
        "typescript": "^4.0.0",
        "vite": "^2.1.0"
    }
```

Comment: sveltekit is in early development, they say you are on your own because its still buggy

Comment: Yes, I know, but if anyone knew how to fix it, that would have been nice

Comment: I am also facing same issue

Comment: Hi @NikunjRatanpara, the problem was simply that it was not there in the package.json, so i had to download it again